# Rails RABL display collection as object and child in this object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I have such index.rabl:

```
collection @exchangers, :root => "bank", :object_root => false

extends "exchanger_lists/show"
```

and such show.rabl:

```
object @exchanger
attributes :id, :name, :address, :location_id, :latitude, :longitude, :exchanger_type_id
node(:location_name) {|exchanger_list| exchanger_list.location.name }
node(:exchanger_type_name) {"normal" }
child @currencies do
      attribute :value, :direction_of_exchange_id, :exchanger_list_id
end
```

my contoller is such:

```
def index
    @exchangers = ExchangerList.all
  end
 def show
    @exchanger = ExchangerList.find(params[:id])
    @currency_list = CurrencyList.all
    @currencies = []
    @currency_list.each do |c|
      @currencies << CurrencyValue.find(:all, :conditions => {:currency_list_id => c.id, :exchanger_list_id => @exchanger.id}, :order => :updated_at).last(2)
    end
    @currencies.flatten!
  end
```

if i call in browser show method, i see child @currencies and it's data, but if i call index i see all (also i see nodes) but child i didn't see.... What's wrong? what i do bad?

Comment: Do you mean you see no @currencies child nodes? This instance variable will be nil when you call index and only render the show template.

Comment: @dan yes, maybe you are right.... but how can then i solve my problem?

Comment: I am not ignore you I posted an answer because of lack of space in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your architecture is a little bit messed up because in the show action you not only display an `@exchanger` but also the complete list of `@currencies` being nil when you render show in the index template. In general I would suggest you to think about the whole app architecture.

When I should give you a simple solution for you current problem I would extract the @currencies code from the show action into helper method in app/helpers/currencies_helper.rb and access it from the show template.

```
module CurrenciesHelper

  def currencies(exchanger)
    currencies = CurrencyList.all.map do |c|
      CurrencyValue.find(:all, :conditions => {:currency_list_id => c.id, :exchanger_list_id => exchanger.id}, :order => :updated_at).last(2)
    end
    currencies.flatten!
  end

end
```

By the way I replaced the `each` method with `map` because it suits better in this case.

Change the currencies part in the show template to

```
child currencies(@exchanger) do
  attribute :value, :direction_of_exchange_id, :exchanger_list_id
end
```

Comment: ok, will try, please add information about what to write then in view and method

Comment: in show action all is ok, but in view i get Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4    maybe becouse not all data in db is linked, not all exchangers have currency_values.... is it real to catch it and solve?

Comment: Yo, sorry, I forgot the exchanger attribute in the helper method, I updated my answer.

Comment: hm( realy strange, but now is not working to.... only if i delete :exchanger_list_id => exchanger.id then all is ok

Comment: ok, but this seems to be an issue of the available data and as I told you your architecure is generally a little bit confuse, e.g. I don't no why for you a exchanger_list_id is the same as an exchanger.id, I only answered you problem why no currencies are displayed when calling the index action

Comment: ok.... also exchanger_list_id  is in currency_values model, but exchanger.id in exchanger_list   with model all is ok, it couldn't be in other way

Comment: all i must to write was: currencies(root_object)  )